# Spray Routing with File Upload Actor

Tags: akka, spray

I have an existing Spray application utilizing Spray Routing and I've recently added a File Stream Upload Actor [based on the example](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/examples/spray-can/simple-http-server/src/main/scala/spray/examples/DemoService.scala).

What I can't figure out is how to combine my existing root HttpService actor with my File Upload Actor which does not extend HttpService.

My existing root service actor looks like this:

```
class RootService extends Actor with HttpService with Routes with ActorLogging {
  def receive = runRoute {
      routes
  }
}
```

And my file upload Actor like this:

```
class FileUploadService extends Actor with Logging {
  def receive = {
    case part @ HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/upload"), headers, entity: HttpEntity.NonEmpty, protocol) => {
      val parts = part.asPartStream()
      val client = sender
      val handler = context.actorOf(Props(new FileUploadHandler(client, parts.head.asInstanceOf[ChunkedRequestStart])))
      parts.tail.foreach(handler !)
    }
    case start @ ChunkedRequestStart(HttpRequest(POST, Uri.Path("/upload"), _, _, _)) => {
      val client = sender
      val handler = context.actorOf(Props(new FileUploadHandler(client, start)))
      sender ! RegisterChunkHandler(handler)
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried modifying my root service actor as follows:

```
class RootService extends Actor with HttpService with Routes with ActorLogging {
  val fileUploadActor = context.actorOf(Props[FileUploadService], "fileUploadActor")
  def receive = runRoute {
    pathPrefix("upload") {
        fileUploadActor ! _.request
    } ~ {
      route
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work properly. Ultimately the response never makes it back to the client (even if I specify ask vs tell).

Any suggestions on a working implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In the RootService, send the RequestContext to the upload actor:

```
def receive = runRoute {
 pathPrefix("upload") {
   ctx => fileUploadActor ! ctx
 }
}
```

Then in the file upload service, you can use runRoute in the same way as the RootService, and complete the request within that service. If you have a reference to the RequestContext, there is no need to reply to the RootService.